# UIButton is not refreshing inside thread

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, nsthread

I have a method inside a thread. Before tthe calling of the thread, I disabled a button, and I can see the button eith the alpha changed.
Inside the thread, I'm calling the async method AVAssetExportSession and then, I enable the button.
The button works perfectly but the alpha is not changing every time immediately. Sometimes is after 0.1 seconds, sometimes is after 4 seconds.
I tried to execute the enable in the main thread, but I have the same problem.
Any clue about it?
Thanx

UPDATE: I will try to write some code.

```
                        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(importaVideo:) toTarget:self withObject:arrayParam];
```

And this is the method called:

```
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:[Utilidades getQualityExport]];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[Utilidades devuelvePath:filenameVideo]];
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            self.buttonSettings.enabled = YES;
}];
```

I know that this is not the complete code, but the other part is a little complex and is not affecting to the final result.

Comment: add your try code.

Comment: show us your tried code

Comment: Update you UI related stuff on main thread, It should work.

Comment: @Prakash I tried using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
but didn't work